# Office 2013 style window

Tags: c#, winforms

Do you know how I can render exactly this kind of window in WinForms (Outlook2013 style, thin border, shadow, small 'X' button)?

[Outlook2013-style window http://imageshack.com/a/img661/2893/4Pwt5V.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/2893/4Pwt5V.png)

I need to modify layout for an already existing Outlook addin so that it resembles this window in particular. I know that I can play with border frame, winAPI calls etc. but is there a better way to do this?

Any advice will be appreciated. I searched throughout Google and it seems that no one has had a similar issue.

Best Regards,
Maciej

Comment: You could probably make the window borderless and use your own controls inside it, drawing them yourself.

Comment: This form is built using WPF controls. Try using them on top of your Windows Form, of course, borderless.